# Telnet using python example not working

Tags: python, telnet

I have tried the below code as mentioned in python.org. As per the code, it asks for the remote account and password but nothing happens beyond that. The script waits for a couple of minutes and then just exits.

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

Am I missing something here?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you have a running telnet server?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not have a telnet server running on the host you are attempting to run the code on. You should adjust the "HOST" variable to point to a host that does have telnetd running, or install a telnet server on your machine. Here's a few ways to install a telnet server depending on your operating system:

Linux: Use your package manager to install telnetd or telnet-server. This will vary on your OS. [Here's a guide for Ubuntu](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux) and [one for CentOS/RHEL](https://www.unixmen.com/installing-telnet-centosrhelscientific-linux-6-7/).

OSX: Easiest way is probably using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) - `brew install telnetd`. [Here's a good answer on StackExchange with more info](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314239/how-to-enable-telnet-server-on-macos-10-13-1).

Windows: You can try [this guide](https://techjourney.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-service-in-windows/). Of note, when I was browsing for guides on Windows, a couple sites seemed to suggest telnet server was removed as of Windows Server 2012 and Windows 10, but I have not verified this myself.